# Persistent Notification Message with switch (ON/OFF) on Android/iOS?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, push-notification

I have a mobile app implemented in React Native where the user has a status online/offline.  I want to implement a persistent notification message that shows up whenever the user status is Online, even if the app in the background.

I know that there is a possibility to do actions within notifications like pause button in the media player apps. How could this be done in react-native?

Comment: if you can use react-native-push-notification, you can set notification status to 'ongoing'.

Comment: @dzgeek what status `ongoing` do

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setOngoing(boolean), notification cannot be dismissed by user. switch offline/online and clear it programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

Use https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification

If you want to make it sticky you can set :

PushNotification.localNotification({
ongoing:true
)}
You can use ongoing property of this library to make sticky notification

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into https://github.com/testshallpass/react-native-dropdownalert I think it would offer exactly what you need

Answer (score 0):

You can use FCM for push notification.

Package details :
https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm

First you need to store user vise device token into your database. Then if user's status changes to online you can send FCM notification to set of device tokens or just one you set. So notification will pop on your device.

Hope this is what your are looking for.